# Can't clone github repo using SSH even though I can connect to github using SSH

Tags: github, ssh, authorization, public-key, repo

I have created key files in my windows machine using `ssh-keygen` and I got a .pub file and another file which is the key, and it's a string that looks like:

```
 -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- 
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

After that, I then added that key file to my ssh-agent using `ssh-add`. And I made sure it was added by running `ssh-add -l -E sha256`. From that command I got the fingerprint string of my key file.

Then, I went to github to the repo I wish to clone via SSH, and I went to my profile->>settings->>sshKeyys and I had no keys yet, so I added a new one, and as a key I uploaded my .pub file's contents which was a string that started with "ssh-rsa XXXX". After that, it was successfully added on github and I can see the fingerprint of that key I've just added at github's page, and it matches with the one I see on my windows machine when I ran `ssh-add -l -E sha256`, so it's the same fingerprint. Even though the fingerprint I see on my machine was the result of adding the private key to the ssh-agent, while this one at github is actually the .pub file, so I don't know if they are supposed to give the same fingerprint despite the one I see on my machine comes from the key file (the one with the string starting with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`  ) , and the one from github comes from the .pub file (the one with the string starting with `ssh-rsa XXXX`.

Anyways, I tried to check the connection worked by running `ssh -vT git@github.com` and it worked, and in the verbose logs it shows that the client (my pc) is sending the same fingerprint file that I see when I run `ssh-add -l -E sha256` (which also matches with the key I created at github), it also says that the server accepted that fingerprint. The final message is `Hi <my_username> ! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

So this shows that the ssh connection from my pc to github apparently works.

Finally, I go back to my repo and instead of copying the regular HTTP string to clone the repo, I copy the SSH string which is in the form `git@github.com:<user>/<repo_name>.git`

So then at my windows machine I open a git bash terminal and type `git clone git@github.com:<user>/<repo_name>.git`.

But I get this error

```
Cloning into '<filepath>'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Which is rare, since the `ssh -vT git@github.com` connection worked using the key files just generated by `ssh-keygen`. So I thought that my github user was not authorized to pull from that repo (it's not mine, it's an organization), but if I try the regular HTTP method to clone it works, just the SSH way doesn't works.

Am I missing something here? I've already checked lots of documentations and I don't find a case where a ssh connection to github works using the specified keys, but the cloning through SSH doesn't even though HTTP cloning does.

Answer (score 0):

The `.pub` file should be a public key, starting with, for instance `ssh-rsa ...`

`ssh-add` is used [when your private key is encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129727).

In your git bash sesion, type:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

You will check if your key is proposed by SSH or not.

If said key has [a default name](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys), like `~/.ssh/[id_rsa|id_edcsa|id_ed25519]`, SSH will try those.

If not, you need a `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /path/to/my/key (not the .pub)
```

Comment: what is the `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'` command for ? I understand that it creates a variable called `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` whose value will be the string "ssh -Ty" . But should it do something besides that? I mean, I ran it and it doesn't returns any output. And when I run "$GIT_SSH_COMMAND" the output is 'ssh -Ty' .

Anyways, I've tried `ssh -vT git@github.com` and it does uses my right keys by looking at the fingerprints. I don't know is this what you were referring to with the `ssh -Tv` ?

Comment: @Eugenio.Gastelum96 It will do the git clone and display SSH details when git does the SSH access.